# Qt5: Text ID based translations. Add custom Parameters to uic

Tags: qt4, qt5, translation, uic

I'm using Qt 5.9 for my project and I have to use ID based translations. My problem is, that I can't change the parameters for the uic executable. The qmake variable "QMAKE_UIC" has been removed in Qt 5.

Does anyone know, how I can add the parameter "-tr qtTrId" to the uic command so that I'm able to use ID based translations with .ui files? Or is there another way to tell qmake to use ID based translations?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. Add this to the .pro file:

```
load (uic)
uic.commands += -tr qtTrId
```